# Get Value Listview Item from asyntask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-async-http

How to get value when i clicked an item on custom listview which have data from asynctask, i clicked on item , how can i get a value of that paticular item id which come from in json format.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();

        try {
            JSONObject object= new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject ob= object.getJSONObject("userdetail");
            String profile_pic=ob.getString("user_profile_pic");
            String  name= ob.getString("user_login");

            String listing_count=object.getString("listening_count");
            String listen= object.getString("listener_count");
            String des=ob.getString("user_description");
            ((App) User_Post.this.getApplication()).setName(name);
            ((App) User_Post.this.getApplication()).setDesc(des);
            ((App) User_Post.this.getApplication()).setImg(profile_pic);
            if(object.has("posts")){
                Log.e("post", "Post entry");

                JSONArray posts= object.getJSONArray("posts");

                total=posts.length();
                Log.e("post", "Post entry"+total);
                for(int i=0; i<posts.length();i++){
                    Post_pojo po= new Post_pojo();
                    JSONObject json= posts.getJSONObject(i);
                     a= json.getString("text_post");
                     **user_post=json.getString("ID").toString();**

                po.setText_post(a);
                search.add(po);

                }
                Log.e("result", ""+user_post);
            //  post.setText(total);

            }else{
                //post.setText("0");
                total=0;
                Log.e("post", "Post entry0");
            }
            Log.e("result", ""+profile_pic);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            URL newurl = new URL(profile_pic); 
      Bitmap img;

        img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
         profile.setImageBitmap(img);
         username.setText(name);
         listners.setText(listen);
         listings.setText(listing_count);
         desc.setText(des);
         post.setText(""+total);
         Custom_post custom= new Custom_post(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_post, search);
         list.setAdapter(custom);
    } ///--- Exception---///


    }
```

list view on-click listener :

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        TextView user= (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.detail);
         list_user_name=user.getText().toString();
        Log.e("user name", ""+list_user_name);
        us= (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            Intent in = new Intent(User_Post.this, Teaching.class);
            in.putExtra("text", list_user_name);
            **in.putExtra("user_post", user_post);**
            Log.e("post", ""+user_post);

            ActivityStack ac=(ActivityStack)getParent();
            ac.startChildActivity("Posts", in);
         }
       });
    }
```

Comment: use `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)` and then  get the item you want

Comment: but i want the id which come with that item(which is in json format)

Comment: you can add a setter and getter in your model class. I assume search is list of objects. so you can use the above and get id also

Comment: for example i send a comment which have id also then i want id of any comment by clicking on that comment